# Is there a good web app for manipulating .pdf files?

Tags: webapp-rec, pdf

I'm looking to merge a couple .pdf files for a one-off and don't want to install anything on my PC.

Anyone know of any web apps which will let me merge .pdf files?

Answer (score 0):

You can [use Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=50092) to upload, modify and combine PDFs, then output it as a new PDF.  Might cause some formatting issues if the PDF contents are really funky, but it's free and easy and you probably already have a Google account.

Comment: How can you modify & combine PDFs? Can you please provide the steps

Answer (score 0):

While *not a webapp*, you may be interested in [PDFTK Builder Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/pdftk_builder_portable) - a version of PDFTK Builder that can be run without installation on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PDF Mergy](http://pdfmerge.w69b.com). Allows to merge pdf files with a drag and drop interface. Requires a recent HTML5-capable web browser.

I know this comes a bit late, but maybe it helps anybody who happens to stumble across this.

Answer (score 0):

[PDF Rider](http://pdfrider.codeplex.com/) is an open source project on Codeplex. This utility provides a GUI for the command-line program Pdftk.

[PDFSAM (PDF Split and Merge)](http://www.pdfsam.org/) is another free, open source utility to split and merge pdf files.

[I've tried both in the past & found PDF Rider to be faster than PDFSAM](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/12/manipulate-pdf-files-for-free-with.html).

Answer (score -1):

[MergePDF.net](http://www.mergepdf.net/)

> This service enables you to combine PDF documents into a single one, free of charge. All you need to do is select the PDF documents that you want to merge together on your computer and click a button, as instructed below.

1. [pdfonline.com](http://www.pdfonline.com/premium/Merge.aspx)
2. [PDFJoin](http://www.pdfjoin.com/)
3. [PDFHammer](http://www.nitropdf.com/free/hammer/index.htm)

Comment: if pdfonline is point 1 does that make MergePDF 0 ? :)